# Ruby on Rails: How to model a User is the "owner" of an Item?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to be able to query **user.items** and **item.owner**, in code:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :owner, :class_name => "User"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # What goes here?
  has_many :items
end
```

I added to the Item model a column owner_id, how do I construct the User model so it uses owner_id instead of user_id when I call user.items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The item table need to contain a user_id column. If you want to set this key by hand then you should use:

```
... ,:foreign_key => 'owner_id'
```

Have a look at:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

and

[Defining foreign key relationships for Rails' models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904421/defining-foreign-key-relationships-for-rails-models)