# Display user_id to username

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Rails newbie here. I'm trying to display a user's name when they post something. However, it keeps on showing the user_id (integer). I would like to display their actual name. I wired everything correctly. Here is the code. Thanks.

in post/index.html.erb.....@user.username will show an undefined method error.

```
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>

    <!--posts table!-->
    <div class="container">
      <% @posts.each do |post| %>
        <div class="panel panel-info">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
              <%= post.title %>
          <div class="pull-right">
            <%= @user.username %> |
            <%= time_ago_in_words(Time.now) %>
          </div>
        </h3>
      </div>  
      <div class="panel-body">
        <%= post.description %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Is username column present in your table?

Comment: `@user` is not defined in your `index` action in controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
<%= post.user.username %>
```

```
<!--posts table!-->
<div class="container">
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<div class="panel panel-info">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h3 class="panel-title">
<%= post.title %>
<div class="pull-right">
<%= post.user.username %> | #here
<%= time_ago_in_words(Time.now) %>
</div>
</h3>
</div>  
<div class="panel-body">
<%= post.description %>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

`<%= post.user_id %>` will always give the integer value(**`user_id is integer`**).If you want to show the **`associated username`**,then you have to do `<%= post.user.username %>`

**Note:** Sorry for the format.I like it to be like that.

Answer (score 1):

To give you some more input - what `Pavan` described is all to do with the [ActiveRecord associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) in Rails:

```
#app/models/post.rb
belongs_to :user
```

This creates another method on your parent object (`@post.user`), which will populate with the data referenced by the [`foreign_key`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904421/defining-foreign-key-relationships-for-rails-models) in your parent object. For example, you have `user_id` in your `Post` model - that will be translated into `.user` for use in your view

This means you'll be able to call `@post.user.name` to get the username or whatever attribute you have in your `User` model

--

[**Delegate**](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate)

But there's more!!

You'll benefit from the [`.delegate`](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) method - which basically allows you to treat methods in an associated controller as the parent's:

```
#app/models/post.rb
belongs_to :user
delegate :name, to: :user, prefix: true #-> creates post.user_name
```

This means you'll be able to call the delegated methods on your parent model directly (like how you've got it right now)